# Add frosting/blur effect to Bootstrap 3 fixed navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There are a couple examples out there for what I am looking for, one in the link below.  But I am trying to perform this effect either on a background color or image using stock Bootstrap 3 nav classes.  Is this possible do you think.  Every time I get close the whole nav is blurred rather than just the background.

What I am looking for:

http://codepen.io/adobe/pen/d056d1b26b9683c018f9bb9e0f1b0e1c

```
-webkit-filter: blur(20px);
-moz-filter: blur(20px);
-o-filter: blur(20px);
-ms-filter: blur(20px);
filter: blur(20px);
opacity: 0.4;
```

I am using this setup for bootstrap:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you.

Comment: Here is another good link/example: http://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/WtQjY/415/

Comment: Here is another one. I just cant get the content in the nav bar to not be blurry, it is blurring everything? http://abduzeedo.com/ios7-frosted-glass-effect-html-5-and-javascript

Comment: Where is the code your using?

Comment: Perhaps show what you have tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quick bootply http://www.bootply.com/BYInEV4LVu

Adding that blur code you posted to the navbar will blur everything in it, so what you want to do is to set the background of the nav to be semitransparent and give it a z-index to keep it on top. Then add another bar beneath the #navbar and position it the same as the .navbar but underneath it using z-index. Below is where the extra blur div should go and the blur code.
html

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid the-navbar">
        <div class="navbar-header"> ... </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse"> ... </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        <div class="the-blur"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```css
.the-blur {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    z-index:1010;
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
    -moz-filter: blur(20px);
    -o-filter: blur(20px);
    -ms-filter: blur(20px);
    filter: blur(20px);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `backdrop-filter: blur(10px);`

For more info see: [My Github Repo for adding frosty effect to Bootstrap navbar](https://github.com/thisisjaymehta/CSS-Frosty-Navbar)

Comment: Note: this property has terrible browser support, 3 years after original comment. Safari requires webkit prefix, IE 11 not supported at all. Firefox only supported if manually enabled: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter

Comment: I know. I am looking for a way around to add this effect using some other way.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks user3365721 and arshad.  I have done more research and what I am looking for can't be done without some Javascript as shown in the below example:

http://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/WtQjY/415/

```
            $(function () {
                html2canvas($("body"), {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        $(".blurheader").append(canvas);
                        $("canvas").attr("id", "canvas");
                        stackBlurCanvasRGB(
                            'canvas',
                        0,
                        0,
                        $("canvas").width(),
                        $("canvas").height(),
                        20);
                    }
                });
                vv = setTimeout(function () {
                    $("header").show();
                    clearTimeout(vv);
                }, 200);
            });

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                $("canvas").css(
                    "-webkit-transform",
                    "translatey(-" + $(window).scrollTop() + "px)");
            });

            window.onresize = function () {
                $("canvas").width($(window).width());
            };

            $(document).bind('touchmove', function () {
                $("canvas").css(
                    "-webkit-transform",
                    "translatey(-" + $(window).scrollTop() + "px)");
            });

            $(document).bind('touchend', function () {
                $("canvas").css(
                    "-webkit-transform",
                    "translatey(-" + $(window).scrollTop() + "px)");
            });
```

***  You will see here that the text and everything behind the menubar is blurred not jus the bar.  That is where I was having trouble.

I just need to apply this now to Bootstraps framework and classes.

Thank you for all your time though you helped confirm to me that I was doing it right but need to

Comment: I still cant do it. Do you have a perfect working example other than the link you gave?

Comment: JavaScript's purpose is to manipulate DOM elements. CSS is for styling the DOM elements. You absolutely should not require any JavaScript to do what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

just use
backdrop-filter

```css
.navibar {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.815);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: -100;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.navibar::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.hope ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.hope li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 35px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.hope li img {
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
.hope li a {
  color: rgb(158, 158, 158);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.hope li a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.hope li a img {
  margin-bottom: -8px;
}

.hope a .o {
  margin-bottom: -7px;
}
.hope ul .pls {
  padding-left: 300px;
}
.hope ul .plss {
  padding-right: 350px;
}
```

```html
<header class="navibar">
      <div class="navi">
        <nav class="hope">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGWBCRLJph7pEByaL5Un9tQ"><img src="Images/Screenshot 2021-07-15 173623-modified.png" width="28" height="28">Subscribe!</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://discord.gg/9cCuPzHwN7">Discord Sever</a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:mncfred1505@gmail.com">Email me</a></li>
            <li><a href="tel:+819091615828">Call me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#aboutme">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#meme">Memes</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

it worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You said you want the effect(as in the example) in the navbar. You can just give a transparent background color to your navbar.


### Demo

CSS:

```
.navbar{
 background:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
```

Comment: That does not blur the navbar, which is what was originally asked.

Comment: Transparency is not what this question is about.